# Can't Retrieve Wallets transactions using web3js

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js, erc20

I tried to get all the transactions of a wallet address on a certain token contract. But it keeps on returning null.

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

const web3 = new Web3('https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com/v1/___')

const abi = [contains correct abi]
const contract_address = '0x----------'
const wallet_address = '0x2-----------'

var instance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract_address)
instance.getPastEvents(
    "Transfer",
    {filter: {to: wallet_address }},
    { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: "latest" },
    (errors, events) => {
       if (!errors) {
            console.log(events);
       }
            console.log(errors);
       }
);
```

I don't know what's wrong with it; maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Can't tell without the contract address. But it's possible that the contract does not have the `to` indexed field in the `Transfer` event. Either it has a different name or it's not indexed.

Comment: Also, the RPC doesn't allow fetching more than 1k blocks at a time. `{"error":{"message":"Blockheight too far in the past: eth_getLogs. Range of blocks allowed for your plan: 1000","code":-32005},"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1}`